# The link "show [1] more comments" doesn't work on the mobile site

Tags: bug, mobile

As the title says, the link "Show [1] more comments" simply doesn't work.

[image]

Note, that you have to be *logged out* to see this behavior.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201627/show-n-more-comments-cannot-be-clicked-on-mobile-browser-when-not-logged-in describes exactly this problem